# What is the general mathematical definition of periodic motion?

Tags: kinematics, definition

What is the general mathematical definition  of periodic motion?

**My answer :** Can you say that each function is in the form $ \overrightarrow{r} (t)= \overrightarrow{r} (t+T)$.

it is right?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicFunction.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function, etc.

Comment: Note that this definition would preclude something like (under) damped harmonic motion to be included in the definition of "periodic motion".

Answer (score 1):

https://www.britannica.com/science/periodic-motion

"Periodic motion, in physics, motion repeated in equal intervals of time. Periodic motion is performed, for example, by a rocking chair, a bouncing ball, a vibrating tuning fork, a swing in motion, the Earth in its orbit around the Sun, and a water wave. ... Simple harmonic motion is a special case of periodic motion."

So to answer your question
$\overrightarrow{r} (t)= \overrightarrow{r} (t+T)$
describes periodic motion.

See
https://brilliant.org/wiki/identifying-periodic-motion/
which has your exact equation as the mathematical definition of periodic motion.

{However damped harmonic motion would not be periodic motion since it does not exactly repeat because of the damping factor}